# Slick evolutions with transactions

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-evolutions

I have a question about using Play + Slick, and the slick evolutions.

Someone told me to always wrap the evolutions statements in a transaction (in order not to leave the DB with half evolution applied). In the case we were seeing, with Postgres it would mean to start the Up/Down with a `BEGIN;` and end with a `COMMIT;`

1st I find it hard to remember in every evolution to put those keywords.

2nd I find it hard to believe that play/slick doesn't already have an option/configuration to do that.

So, is there any way to make play/slick to wrap every evolution in a transaction in order not to leave an evolution half applied? (I saw the `autocommit` config but not sure if that's what I want: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Evolutions#Evolutions-configuration)

ps: using Play 2.4.x with slick 2.1.0, if relevant (but would also like to know about other versions)